# SPARQL in Protege 4.3

Tags: sparql, protege, protege4

I need to return individuals for my query:

```
SELECT ?subject ?class
            WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?class. 
?class rdfs:comment "linear"@en}
```

But it works only with subclasses. Should I replace `rdfs:subClassOf` on different operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query specifically asks for **?subject**s that are subclasses of **?class** (where **?class** has the **rdfs:comment "linear"@en**). To retrieve *instances* of type **?class**, you'd use

```
?subject rdf:type ?class
```

or, since SPARQL allows abbreviating **rdf:type** by **a**,

```
?subject a ?class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't share details about the body of data, you are querying, you might want to get an idea yourself by checking

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?subject ?class
WHERE
{ ?s ?p ?class . 
  ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?class . 
  ?class rdfs:comment "linear"@en .
} ORDER BY ?s ?p ?subject ?class
```

and/or

```
SELECT ?subject ?class ?p ?o
WHERE
{ ?subject ?p ?o .
  ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?class . 
  ?class rdfs:comment "linear"@en .
} ORDER BY ?subject ?class ?p ?o
```

from where you can expand in the same manner until you get a handle.